# WPF hyperlink in datatemplate listboxitem

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a data template in WPF that is attached to a ResultsViewModel class and renders the VM in a table format. A bunch of these make up ListBoxItems in a ListBox. What I want is in each individual table to have a little X at the top right of the border where if you click it, it calls a function that removes that item from the listbox.

I have tried with a Hyperlink and event OnClick but then I have to have the DataTemplate in the main XAML and not in a resource dictionary as it needs a x:Class tag to use events, but then the event gets fired in the MainViewModel, which isn't the worst thing in the world as the observable list is held in the MainViewModel and needs to be removed at that point anyway, but I can't figure out how to get a reference to the ResultsViewModel of the list box item that contained the data template that was clicked

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ErroredResultsTemplate" DataType="x:Type vm:ResultsViewModel" >
        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResultProcessedBorder}" Background="{StaticResource ResultFill}" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="10" Margin="6" Padding="5" Width="110" Height="110">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="83" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Foreground="{StaticResource ResultGrayText}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Hyperlink Click="Close_Results">X</Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Width="90" Text="An error occurred calculating results" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource ResultGrayText}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Instead of a Hyperlink with an event handler, why don't you use a `Button` with a Command and let this command reside wherever you want(use a RelativeSource FindAncestor to ListBox if you want to access the Command from the ListBox's DataContext) and set the `CommandParameter` of the command as `{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in two ways:

1. Create a property of type `ResultsViewModel` in your parent view model (that contains your collection of `ResultsViewModel` objects) and bind that to the `SelectedItem` property of your `ListBox`. Add some kind of `RelayCommand` to the parent view model to handle the delete action, add a `Button` to your `DataTemplate` and bind its `Command` property to the new command. Then, when any delete button is clicked, you can just remove the item found in the `SelectedItem` property from your collection and the UI should update accordingly (assuming that you've implemented the `INotifyPropertyChange` interface).
2. You can simply bind from the `DataTemplate` of each item in the `ListBox` to the parent view model directly. This assumes that you have a `Command` in your parent view model named `Delete` and that the parent view model is bound to the `DataContext` property of the `Window` or `UserControl` that the `ListBox` appears in. Also note the important `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` part which passes the data object from each item in the collection to the `object` parameter in the `Command` when a `Command` is called.

Example:

```
<Button Content="X" Command="{Binding DataContext.Delete, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type 
    XmlNameSpace:WindowOrUserControlName}}, Mode=OneWay}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```